# How can I migrate data from Oracle 11gR2 database table to MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I would like to transfer a large table from Oracle Database 11gR2 to MySQL 5.5. Anyone please suggest me how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unload the data in Oracle to a text file by using Load/Unload wizards in the Oracle Database XE graphical user interface.

Then using LOAD DATA statement to load data into MySQL from that text file.

Default Setting is OK.